CSS control buttons
I need to design 4 buttons like this. Consider the sides and buttons sides are solid.
Give The 4 buttons pizza cutting shape as the buttons are the slice of pizza. (like the given image)
The design is similar to pizza cutting:
.container {
    border-radius:50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  /*
  How to give buttons desired shapes? Maybe using skew? I am not able doing it.
   */
}



Are you trying to create 4 elements each with those splodgy backgrounds, or are you wanting 4 neat segments with 2 straight and one arc-ed sides?

Now we know that straight/arc edges are wanted, this can be done in a very few lines of CSS  using clip-path to create a segment and transform rotate to orientate it.

I created this using Tailwindcss, it should not be hard to convert to vanilla css.
Check it out - https://play.tailwindcss.com/AvNKHh64Nu.
I'll also include the code if you prefer it from using tailwinds' playgroud.
<div 
  class="flex h-screen w-screen items-center justify-center"
>
  <div 
    class="relative size-56 overflow-hidden rounded-full bg-gray-300"
  >
    <button 
      class="absolute -top-6 left-14 size-28 rotate-45 bg-red-500 transition hover:bg-red-600 active:bg-red-400" 
      title="you are hovering red"
    ></button>
    <button 
      class="absolute -right-6 top-14 size-28 rotate-45 bg-blue-500 transition hover:bg-blue-600 active:bg-blue-400" 
      title="you are hovering blue"
    ></button>
    <button 
      class="absolute -bottom-6 left-14 size-28 rotate-45 bg-yellow-500 transition hover:bg-yellow-600 active:bg-yellow-400" 
      title="you are hovering yellow"
    ></button>
    <button 
      class="absolute -left-6 top-14 size-28 rotate-45 bg-green-500 transition hover:bg-green-600 active:bg-green-400" 
      title="you are hovering green"
    ></button>
  </div>
</div>

Preview of final result (obviously change color, sizes, etc. to match your design, this is just the general idea of how to produce your request).

